# как связать php и index.html

Tags: php

должна отправляться заявка на почту. это мой первый пхп код, прошу не судить строго, и конкретно указать на ошибки.

index.html

```
<div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Оставить заявку</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <form action="order.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Почта">
                        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Сообщение">
                        <hr>
                        <input type="text" name="utm_source" placeholder="Источник">
                        <input type="text" name="utm_keyword" placeholder="Ключевое слово">
                        <input type="text" name="utm_campaign" placeholder="Кампания">
                        <input type="text" name="utm_sourcersy" placeholder="Площадка">
                        <input type="text" name="utm_medium" placeholder="Тип рекламы">
                        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Город">
                      </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default">Отправить</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

order.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

date_default_timezone_set(«UTC»);
// $to = "89191020010@mail.ru, mirus@mirusdesk.kz";
$to = "zh.zhanelya@gmail.ru, trip.decode.kz";
$subject = "3Dlevel - Новая заявка";

$message = ' 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>'.$subject.'</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <h2>'.$subject.'</h2>

if($_POST["send"]==true){

    <p>Имя: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>
    <p>Телефон: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>
    <p>Почта: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>
    <p>' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Источник: ' . $_POST['utm_source'] . '</p>
    <p>Ключевое слово: ' . $_POST['utm_keyword'] . '</p>
    <p>Кампания: ' . $_POST['utm_campaign'] . '</p>
    <p>Площадка: ' . $_POST['utm_sourcersy'] . '</p>
    <p>Тип рекл.: ' . $_POST['utm_medium'] . '</p>
    <p>Город: ' . $_POST['city'] . '</p>
  }
  </body> 
</html>';

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
$headers .= 'To: zh.zhanelya@gmail.com <zh.zhanelya@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
// $headers .= 'To: saparjumabekov@gmail.com <saparjumabekov@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Baby-Club <lead@baby-club.tk>\r\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
  echo "da";
}
else{
  echo "net";
}
```

Comment: <h2>'.$subject.'</h2> не закрыли ковычку

Comment: оффтоп: Высылать сообщения лучше с помощью уже готовой библиотеки, например [swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/download)

Comment: @Владислав Нет, не лучше, а проще. Чтобы не создавать лишнего веса на проект, лучше использовать стандартные функции(не всегда конечно)

Comment: @DenisLazarev по моему и лучше и проще. Подобные библиотеки не такие уж и энергоемкие, а использование их оставляет код чистым и читабельным. Особенно, если нужно в проекте все время менять данные для SSL или TLS, и мест, где надо это все менять в проекте множество(контакт, уведомления, newsletter и тд).

Comment: @Владислав Просто можно данный код перестроить, разбив его на методы и он будет уже наглядно читабельнее. Но по возможности лучше избавляться от тех библиотек, от которых можно отказаться. Без обид))) это лично мое мнение

Comment: @DenisLazarev тогда можно и от фреймворков отказаться. Но почему-то ни одного спеца не встретишь, который работает на стандартных функциях. Наши комменты могут удалить, слишком посредственно темы касается. И кстати, у меня, что старые проекты на чистом php, что примерно тоже самое по сложности на Symfony 3 грузятся одинаково быстро. Клиент разницы не заметит никакой :)

Answer (score 2):

В переменной $message php код не будет выполняться.

Сделайте СНАЧАЛА проверку на присутствие $_POST['send']. И потом сразу же генерируйте $message без ненужных условий. Примерно код будет выглядеть так.

```
<php 
if($_POST['send']){
   $message = "здесь сообщение, которое вам нужно выслать";

   и здесь же производите отправку сообщения.
   В вашем примере отправка будет происходить во время каждого запуска файла. А этого, думаю, делать не стоит.

   header(Location: возвращаемся на страницу); 
}
>
```